# Consecutive Prime Problem

Tags: sequences-and-series, prime-numbers, pattern-recognition

Consecutive primes whose quotient of their product and sum is itself a prime number.

$$ 2 \times 3 \times 5 = 30 $$

$$ 30/10 = 3 $$

$$ 3 \times 5 \times 7 = 105 $$

$$ 105/15 = 7 $$

Question: Amateur question, but is there a way to check for other consecutive primes which meet this criteria without having to write custom code like I see so often? What's the next sequence of primes like this? If I could learn a way do that kind of calculation for this and all future problems it would save me a lot of time.

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the edit. Still learning the system.

Comment: Suppose $5\leq p<q<r$ are consecutive primes. Then $p+q+r<3r<pr<qr<pqr$ so it must be that $p+q+r=pq$. That's all I got so far. Looking forward to seeing someone's answer.

Comment: @quanta See [the highest voted question of Meta.M.SE](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). Warning - the mathjax takes heck of a long time to load!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $5\leq p<q<r$ are consecutive primes. Then 
$$
p+q+r<3r<pr<qr<pqr
$$
so it must be that
$$
p+q+r=pq.
$$
By Bertrand's postulate, $r<2q$. It follows that
$$
(p-1)q=p+r<q+2q=3q.
$$
So it must be that $p+r=2q$ but then $p-1=2$ so that $p=3$. In other words, there are no solutions for $5\leq p<q<r$. The solutions you checked must be the only ones.

---

**Generalizations**: for **four** consecutive primes, you can either adapt the argument above or use this simple observation: suppose $p<q<r<s$ are consecutive primes. By inspection, $p=2$ doesn't work. So suppose $p>2$. But then, $p,q,r,s$ are all odd so that $p+q+r+s$ is even, which in turn implies $pqrs$ is even. This forces $p=2$. A contradiction.

You can now basically repeat this argument for the problem involving $n$ consecutive primes where $n$ is even. For $n$ is odd, pick a clever $N$ so that if $N\leq p_1<p_2<\ldots<p_n$ constitute a solution, then you can use Bertrand's postulate to force 
$$
p_1+p_2+\cdots+p_n=p_1p_2.\tag{*}
$$ 
Using Bertrand's postulate once more,
$$
Np_2\leq p_1p_2=p_1+p_2+\cdots +p_n<p_2+p_2+2p_2+\cdots 2^{n-2}p_2=2^{n-1}p_2.
$$
This should narrow down the possibilities for $p_1$. I have seen that you can sharpen the bound $p_{n+1}<2p_n$ but I can't find a link for that anymore.

Final edit: any $N\geq 1+2^{n-2}$ works.

Comment: Very elegant!${}{}{}$

Comment: Does this include checking for more than three consecutive primes?

Comment: @ quanta: see my extension above.

Comment: @KimJongUn 

Thanks for the swift and thoughtful reply! Unfortunately I'm an amateur at math and only partially understod it all.

1. I understood that for a set of 3, those are the only two solutions.
2. I understood that for any even set, the criteria cannot be met.
3. I did not understand the last part about an odd set.

I tried applying that last line to my first set (n=3)? and was left with  $N\geq 3$ 

Could you clarify what the captial N is in relation to the first prime in the series? i.e how would that apply to one of my examples.

Comment: @ quanta: when I first answered your original question ($n=3$), I chose $5\leq p<q<r$ because you already checked when $p<5$. But you can verify that the argument go through for $3\leq p<q<r$ as well. I bound the smallest prime with $N=1+2^{n-2}$ so that after you apply Bertrand's postulate, the only possibility for $p_1+\cdots+p_n$ is $p_1p_2$. The formula $1+2^{n-2}$ comes from $p_1+p_2+p_3+\cdots+p_n<p_3+p_3+p_3+\cdots+2^{n-3}p_3=(1+2^{n-2})p_3$.